# Difference between LEFT JOIN and LEFT JOIN FETCH in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hql, fetching-strategy

I am trying to understand the difference between `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN FETCH` in Hibernate.

Can anyone explain this?

Thanks

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The "fetch" tells hibernate to load it now instead of letting it be loaded lazily. The reference guide has a [whole chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching) dealing with such things that it's good to be acquainted with.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `FETCH` to tune your application performance. It is one of the orthogonal notions of Hibernate, which answer to the question *how* *(fetch style)* the association is fetched. There are 4 styles: `select` / `subselect` / `batch` / `join`.

The second notion is *when* *(fetch timing)* it should be fetched. You can configure it with the one of the 6 properties defined by Hibernate, where the most 4 properties are: `eager`, `lazy`, `extra lazy`, `proxy`.([hibernate-core](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching))

Hibernate use by default:

- *collection*: lazy select fetching
- *singe-valued assocation*: lazy proxy fetching

**Join**

`JOIN` or (`LEFT JOIN`) will *only* return the parent objects.

**Join fetch**

`JOIN FETCH` (or `LEFT JOIN FETCH`) will **collect all the associations** along with their owner object. Meaning that the collection will be retrieved in the same select. This can be shown by enabling Hibernate's statistics.

A (left/outer) join fetch is great for *ToOne (many-to-one or one-to-one) associations. It is used with non-bags but be aware of the cartesian problem that might occur, when the tables' cardinality is high. Note that a `select` fetch style is in most of the cases faster.

Note that less `select` statements is synonym to less round-trips between hibernate and the database, but it not synonym to a better performance.

Comment: Good read, additional read from Vlad: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59468551/4982691

Comment: When you say "along with their owner object", is the "owner object" the originally queried item, or the one from the joined table?