# What is the difference between JOIN and JOIN FETCH when using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hql, fetch

Please help me understand where to use a regular JOIN and where a JOIN FETCH. For example, if we have these two queries

```
FROM Employee emp
JOIN emp.department dep
```

and

```
FROM Employee emp
JOIN FETCH emp.department dep
```

Is there any difference between them? If yes, which one to use when?

Comment: you can find it here [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) read **14.3. Associations and joins**

Comment: I have gone through that documententation but still don't know where should I use a JOIN and where a JOIN FETCH.

Comment: If you have @oneToOne mapping set to FetchType.LAZY and you use second query(because you need Department objects to be loaded as part of Employee objects) what Hibernate will do is, it will issue queries to fetch Department objects for every individual Employee object it fetches from DB. Later in the code you might access Department objects via Employee to Department single-valued association and Hibernate will not issue any query to fetch Department object for the given Employee. Remember Hibernate still issues queries equal to the number of Employees it has fetched.

Comment: To assist in the doc hunt ~ [Fetching Strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching)

Comment: how to handle if there was no data in department table

Comment: @ShameeraAnuranga I think in that case you will need a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

In this two queries, you are using JOIN to query all employees that have at least one department associated.

But, the difference is: in the first query you are returning only the Employes for the Hibernate. In the second query, you are returning the Employes **and** all Departments associated.

So, if you use the second query, you will not need to do a new query to hit the database again to see the Departments of each Employee.

You can use the second query when you are sure that you will need the Department of each Employee. If you not need the Department, use the first query.

I recomend read this link if you need to apply some WHERE condition (what you probably will need): [How to properly express JPQL "join fetch" with "where" clause as JPA 2 CriteriaQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816417/how-to-properly-express-jpql-join-fetch-with-where-clause-as-jpa-2-criteriaq)

**Update**

If you don't use `fetch` and the Departments continue to be returned, it is because your mapping between Employee and Department (a `@OneToMany`) are setted with `FetchType.EAGER`. In this case, any HQL (with `fetch` or not) query with `FROM Employee` will bring all Departments. Remember that all mapping *ToOne (`@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne`) are EAGER by default.

Comment: Which behaviour will be if we execute statement without fetch and get result. Then within session we will treat to department?

Comment: @gstackoverflow, yes

Comment: I use native query with Lazy fetch in both sides of relationship but still loads hierarchy of child relations.

Comment: Worth mention that `fetch` has to be used if (using our example) you want to order by some Department attribute. Otherwise, (valid at least for PG) you might get `ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

Comment: @Dherik Is there a way to use this query but with nativeQuery=true?

Comment: @Robs If you use `nativeQuery` you are not anymore using the JPQL/HQL language to create queries; you are using plain SQL. So, the `fetch` is not available.

Comment: This answer appears to be the accepted answer but has a glaring error in it. This sentence seems incomplete: "But, the difference is: in the first query you are returning only the Employes for the Hibernate." What is this sentence supposed to say?

Comment: @Michael the first query just return the Employe entities. Maybe the "for the Hibernate" could be removed.

Answer (score 97):

### JOIN

When using `JOIN` against an entity associations, JPA will generate a JOIN between the parent entity and the child entity tables in the generated SQL statement.

So, taking your example, when executing this JPQL query:

```
FROM Employee emp
JOIN emp.department dep
```

Hibernate is going to generate the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT emp.*
FROM employee emp
JOIN department dep ON emp.department_id = dep.id
```

> Note that the SQL `SELECT` clause contains only the `employee` table columns, and not the `department` ones. To fetch the `department` table columns, we need to use `JOIN FETCH` instead of `JOIN`.

### JOIN FETCH

So, compared to `JOIN`, the `JOIN FETCH` allows you to project the joining table columns in the `SELECT` clause of the generated SQL statement.

So, in your example, when executing this JPQL query:

```
FROM Employee emp
JOIN FETCH emp.department dep
```

Hibernate is going to generate the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT emp.*, dept.*
FROM employee emp
JOIN department dep ON emp.department_id = dep.id
```

> Note  that, this time, the `department` table columns are selected as well, not just the ones associated with the entity listed in the `FROM` JPQL clause.

Also, `JOIN FETCH` is a great way to address the [`LazyInitializationException`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/) when using Hibernate as you can initialize entity associations using the `FetchType.LAZY` fetching strategy along with the main entity you are fetching.

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple JOIN FETCH in same query?

Comment: Yes, it's possible for any number of `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` associations and at most one collection.

Answer (score 86):

in [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) i mentioned before on the comment, read this part :

> A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be
> initialized along with their parent objects using a single select.
> This is particularly useful in the case of a collection. **It
> effectively overrides the outer join and lazy declarations of the
> mapping file** for associations and collections.

this "JOIN FETCH" will have it's effect if you have (fetch = FetchType.LAZY) property for a collection inside entity(example bellow).

And it is only effect the method of "when the query should happen". And you must also know [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching):

> hibernate have two orthogonal notions : when is the association fetched and how
> is it fetched. It is important that you do not confuse them. We use
> fetch to tune performance. We can use lazy to define a contract for
> what data is always available in any detached instance of a particular
> class.

when is the association fetched --> your "FETCH" type

how is it fetched --> Join/select/Subselect/Batch

In your case, FETCH will only have it's effect if you have department as a set inside Employee, something like this in the entity:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Department> department;
```

when you use

```
FROM Employee emp
JOIN FETCH emp.department dep
```

you will get `emp` and `emp.dep`. when you didnt use fetch you can still get `emp.dep` but hibernate will process another select to the database to get that set of department.

so its just a matter of performance tuning, about you want to get all result(you need it or not) in a single query(eager fetching), or you want to query it latter when you need it(lazy fetching).

Use eager fetching when you need to get small data with one select(one big query). Or use lazy fetching to query what you need latter(many smaller query).

use fetch when :

- no large **unneeded** collection/set inside that entity you about to get
- communication from application server to **database server too far** and need long time
- you may need that collection latter when you don't have the access to it(**outside** of the **transactional** method/class)

Comment: Could you explain it for the queries that I just wrote in the updated question.

Comment: useful consideration : _"no large unneeded collection/set inside that entity you about to get"_

Comment: Would the departments still be eagerly fetched if the departments inside the employee was a `List` instead of a `Set` ?

Comment: Does using the `FETCH` keyword in an JPQL statement imply an eagerly retrieved property ?

Answer (score 6):

If you have `@oneToOne` mapping set to `FetchType.LAZY` and you use second query (because you need Department objects to be loaded as part of Employee objects) what Hibernate will do is, it will issue queries to fetch Department objects for every individual Employee object it fetches from DB.

Later, in the code you might access Department objects via Employee to Department single-valued association and Hibernate will not issue any query to fetch Department object for the given Employee.

Remember, Hibernate still issues queries equal to the number of Employees it has fetched. Hibernate will issue same number of queries in both above queries, if you wish to access Department objects of all Employee objects

Answer (score 6):

### Difference JOIN and JOIN FETCH in JPQL

**TLDR:** The `FETCH` keyword tells the entityManager to also fetch the associated entities which are joined eagerly (when this is not already the case).

---

Lets say we an user entity and userInfo entity. The user entity has a `@OneToMany` relationship with userInfo as follows:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name= "test_user")
public class User {

    // ... user properties id etc

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user" fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserInfo> infoList;
}
```

And suppose we have the following Queries (this Spring data JPA syntax, however does not matter how JPQL is constructed):

```
@Query("SELECT user FROM User user JOIN user.infoList info")
public List<User> getUsersJoin();

@Query("SELECT user FROM User user JOIN FETCH user.infoList info")
public List<User> getUsersJoinFetch();
```

---

The first Query with only the `JOIN` keyword will generate the following SQL:

```
select u.id, u.email, u.name from test_user u
inner join test_user_data on u.id=test_user_data.user_id;
```

As you can see it will only fetch data from the test_user table and not from the test_user_data table. This can also be seen in the debugger as follows:

[image]

As can be seen we do not have the `List<userData>` on our `User` object because this is not loaded by default.

---

Now lets check out the generated SQL for the Query with `JOIN FETCH`:

```
select test_user.id, data.id, test_user.email, test_user.name, 
data.data, data.user_id, data.user_id, data.id from test_user test_user 
inner join test_user_data data on test_user.id=data.user_id
```

As can be seen we are now fetching the data from both the test_user and the test_user_data table in the join. This can also be seen in the debugger as follows:

[image]

As can be observed we now have access to the `List<userData>` within the `User` Object.

Comment: From this it seems that `join` is plain pointless, which can't be true... right? What am I missing?

Comment: you could still have a condition on the joined table like `... where test_user_data.some_field = some_value`.
This way you get the users, that fulfill the condition, but without the overhead of loading data, that is not needed later on.

Answer (score 2):

Dherik : I'm not sure about what you say, when you don't use fetch the result will be of type : `List<Object[ ]>` which means a list of Object tables and not a list of Employee.

```
Object[0] refers an Employee entity 
Object[1] refers a Departement entity
```

When you use fetch, there is just one select and the result is the list of Employee `List<Employee>` containing the list of departements. It overrides the lazy declaration of the entity.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your concern. If you don't use `fetch`, your query will return only the Employees. If the Departments, even in this case, continue to be returned, is because your mapping between Employee and Department (a @OneToMany) are setted with FetchType.EAGER. In this case, any HQL (with `fetch` or not) query with `FROM Employee` will bring all Departments.

Comment: Without using fetch (join term only), the result would be an array of collections, two rows, the first is a collection of Employees and the second is a collection of Departments. Using eager fetch or lazy fetch, departments will be fetched.

Comment: Without fetch on HQL, this will happen only if your mapping between Employee and Department are EAGER (`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER`). If is not the case, the Departments will not be returned.

Comment: @Dherik try it yourself, You'll get a ClassCastException.

Comment: I figure out the problem. Is not a fetch problem, but how the `select` was made in the HQL. Try `SELECT emp FROM Employee emp JOIN FETCH emp.department dep`. JPA/Hibernate have this behaviour of return a `List` of `Object[]` when you ommit the `SELECT` part.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN FETCH => returns both tables(entities) that you indicated in the JPQL query

JOIN => returns only one table(entity) from JPQL query