# What is the difference between inner join and inner join fetch ? ,HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have this doubt in `HQL` queries

```
"SELECT c from Account c inner join c.person " 
"SELECT c from Account c inner join fetch c.person"
```

Are equals?...When I can use `fetch` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what Koitoer  has mentioned is correct

Additionally
In your Account person is normally set to load lazily, even if you join it in the HQL, the collection person may not load, you have to use 'fetch' to load them.

Answer (score 9):

Fetch join allow to load collection eagerly, it is commonly used when you have relationship that involves collections. It is a way to retrieve eagerly all the records to avoid any problems if the session is closed or you move your object to the view.

[FETCH JOINs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins)

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**: Assuming person is an object inside your Account class

> "SELECT acc from Account acc inner join acc.person"

In this case, Hibernate will return you all the **Account** objects that definitely have a **person** associated with them (i.e. **acc.person** is not null).

However, if your use case requires you to do **acc.getPerson()** later on in your code, **then Hibernate will internally run another query** to fetch the Person object associated with acc [provided session was still open].

Hence, **in order to save that additional query**, it is better to use

> "SELECT acc from Account acc inner join fetch acc.person"

when you know that you will need to use the associated object (Person object in this case) later on.

*Also please refer the answers [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431312/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-join-fetch-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate) for better understanding.*