# Hibernate @OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some trouble with @OneToMany relationship. 
First entity represents some kind of goods.

```
@Entity(name = "ARTIQULE")
public final class ArtiquleEntity extends CustomEntity{

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "METRIC_ID")
public Long metricId;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "STATUS_ID")
public Long statusId;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "NAME")
public String name;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "SHORT_NAME")
public String shortName;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID")
public ArtGroupEntity artGroup;
}
```

Second are being grouping of goods

```
@Entity(name = "AR_GROUP")
public final class ArtGroupEntity extends CustomEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
public Long groupId;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "STATUS_ID")
public Long statusId;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "NAME")
public String name;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "L")
public Integer left;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "R")
public Integer right;

@NotNull
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "artGroup", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<ArtiquleEntity> artiquleEntities;
}
```

When I make a select like "select list from AR_GROUP list".
Hibernate for each group create a select,why it do not use outer join?
Or it is not possible.

```
Hibernate: select artgroupen0_.ID as ID1_0_, artgroupen0_.GROUP_ID as GROUP_ID2_0_, artgroupen0_.L as L3_0_, artgroupen0_.NAME as NAME4_0_, artgroupen0_.R as R5_0_, artgroupen0_.STATUS_ID as STATUS_I6_0_ from AR_GROUP artgroupen0_
Hibernate: select artiquleen0_.GROUP_ID as GROUP_ID2_1_0_, artiquleen0_.ID as ID1_1_0_, artiquleen0_.ID as ID1_1_1_, artiquleen0_.GROUP_ID as GROUP_ID2_1_1_, artiquleen0_.METRIC_ID as METRIC_I3_1_1_, artiquleen0_.NAME as NAME4_1_1_, artiquleen0_.SHORT_NAME as SHORT_NA5_1_1_, artiquleen0_.STATUS_ID as STATUS_I6_1_1_ from ARTIQULE artiquleen0_ where artiquleen0_.GROUP_ID=?
Hibernate: select artiquleen0_.GROUP_ID as GROUP_ID2_1_0_, artiquleen0_.ID as ID1_1_0_, artiquleen0_.ID as ID1_1_1_, artiquleen0_.GROUP_ID as GROUP_ID2_1_1_, artiquleen0_.METRIC_ID as METRIC_I3_1_1_, artiquleen0_.NAME as NAME4_1_1_, artiquleen0_.SHORT_NAME as SHORT_NA5_1_1_, artiquleen0_.STATUS_ID as STATUS_I6_1_1_ from ARTIQULE artiquleen0_ where artiquleen0_.GROUP_ID=?
Hibernate: select artiquleen0_.GROUP_ID as GROUP_ID2_1_0_, artiquleen0_.ID as ID1_1_0_, artiquleen0_.ID as ID1_1_1_, artiquleen0_.GROUP_ID as GROUP_ID2_1_1_, artiquleen0_.METRIC_ID as METRIC_I3_1_1_, artiquleen0_.NAME as NAME4_1_1_, artiquleen0_.SHORT_NAME as SHORT_NA5_1_1_, artiquleen0_.STATUS_ID as STATUS_I6_1_1_ from ARTIQULE artiquleen0_ where artiquleen0_.GROUP_ID=?
```

Thanks for reply.

Comment: I think the Problem will be the OR-Mapping which must be done after the select was executed

Comment: Change the `@ManyToOne` para `@ManyToOne(optional = false)` and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Multiple running queries could be because of the [`n + 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-select-n1) issue.

Use [`JOIN FETCH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431312/difference-between-join-and-join-fetch-in-hibernate) to fetch the parent and all the mapped child entities in one query.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44225287/3094731) similar answer.

Comment: Give due credits to this answer if it helped you. Also so that it is marked as accepted and can  later be picked up by others.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using hql join fetch, 
in my option select look like this

```
from AR_GROUP list left outer join fetch list.artiqules
```