# JPA How to return result without joining other tables?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I'm writing a service with JPA and Postgres db. I have a class named Student:

```
public class Student {
    @id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_phone", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id"))
    private Set<Phone>;

    // Setter and Getter
}
```

And a Phone class:

```
public class Phone {
    @id
    private String id;

    private String number;

    // Setter and Getter
}
```

Now there will be three tables in my db, following are columns in them:

- student: id, first_name, last_name
- phone: id, number
- student_phone: student_id, phone_id

Now every time I query a student from the db, the result contains the corresponding phones. Can I just get the content in student table? Some times I don't want to extend the phone information of a student.

Comment: I cannot coommet yet. but check this Article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431312/difference-between-join-and-join-fetch-in-hibernate

Comment: do you use marshal to xml or joson ?

Answer (score 0):

Use lazy loading

```
 @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
```

or

write native queries

Comment: `@OneToMany` is default lazy

Answer (score 0):

> @OneToMany is default lazy fetch

I assume that you use REST service then:

try this if you use XML in JAXB with `@XmlTransient`:

```
@XmlTransient
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "student_phone", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id"))
private Set<Phone>;
```

or if you use json you can add this `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: Hi Abihabi87, I don't want to use @JsonIgnor because:
1. Sometime I don't want to show phone info bu sometime I want.
2. As I know when I add this annotation, the phone info is still quired from db, but just be ignored by spring-boot. Is it possible that do not retrieve it from db, which could improve the performance.