# Java JPA repository slow on reading

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a database with a quite large entity model.
In total, there are 14 tables with around 100k records on average.

When I tested my application that takes one entity from the database and converts it to json and throws that back to the caller, it took 7 seconds to get the entry.

This doesnt seem an initialization issue because if I do the same call twice in a row, they both take around 10 seconds to get the data.

When I enable sql script logging, I find that for each entity read, hibernate sends hundreds of sql requests to the database.
(The actual number is based on how many connections/licenses/products/services etc the entity has but for my test entry, I got 286 queries (which took around 7 seconds in total))
When the database is empty (except for the data that the test should return), then it takes around 6 seconds.

I suppose the issue is because I have my @OneToMany's and @ManyToMany's fetch set to Lazy, but when I set them to eager, I get the error of multiple fetch bags.

```
@javax.persistence.OneToMany(fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY)
@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "ProductId")
```

This is an example of a OneToMany relation I have, which simulates the eager fetch without the multiple fetch bags error.

Is this a common issue?
And how do I improve the speed on the reading?

Comment: Just how large is your JSON document and how many relations are there? Fetch type should typically be lazy, but if you need to read the world that will always be slow. If a single entity in otherwise empty tables takes 6 seconds it must be huge!

Comment: the resulting json is 2652 lines long formed by a total of 502 records from the database

Comment: Remove the Hibernate-specific LazyCollection annotation, you get the same effect with the portable FetchType.EAGER (which I don't recommend in general). Then see how many queries there are? Do you make 502 selects, or are there a few selects with many results?

Comment: if i set the fetch type to eager, i get a MultipleBagFetchException, the LazyCollection annotation was the solution to that i am not sure what other solutions exist

Comment: I don't want to use eager fetching, I'd suggest using a join fetch or a fetch graph as per the answer below or changing the batch size for reading. However, in order to get that far I'd like to know how many selects there are when the system uses lazy fetching and for how many tables?

Comment: Are you using Lists for the eager fetched collections? If so, try using Sets instead.

Comment: If I just use lazy fetching, I get an org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:  could not initialize proxy - no Session exception... I am using Collection<Entity> everywhere, I could change this to Set, but afaik, it will use Set anyway

Comment: @Wietlol the results you're getting are not really backing that up. The documentation is vague but from what I can tell Hibernate will treat a Collection like a bag type. In any case, you can pre-fetch specific lazy collections by fetching the data with a JPQL query and then using a [JOIN FETCH construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431312/difference-between-join-and-join-fetch-in-hibernate).

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not allow to have more then one collection of type List marked as EAGER.

The best to load the data eager is to use a JOIN FETCH

```
select e from YourEntity JOIN FETCH e.yourList l
```

Another option could be to use an EntityGraph to define the EAGER loading.

Read more about that topic here:

https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/

If you use Spring Data JPA repository interfaces you can use NamedEntityGraphs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph

Comment: I am not using queries with JPQL though, I am using a org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository which makes queries based on the method names of the interface. I prefer to keep the repository approach because of how easy it is to mock a database with it

Comment: Then I would recommend to use EntityGraphs. See my updated answer.

Comment: As far as I can see, it only pulls queries earlier into the process, but it does not decrease the number of queries done.

Comment: You have the classical n+1 read problem. There are several ways to solve that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-select-query-issue?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa