# Make request with subcondition for child list via Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Assume I have the next data model:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Item> items;

    ... getters, setters, equals and hashcode.
}

@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user")
    private User user;

    private Boolean deleted;
    
    ... getters, setters, equals and hashcode.
}
```

I need to query a certain user by id with non-deleted items. Can I do it via Spring Data Repositories?

I tried something like:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("from User u left join u.items i on i.deleted = false where u.id = ?1")
    List<User> findUserWithNonDeletedItems(Long userId);
}
```

But this approach generates 2 separate SQL queries:

```
select user0_.id as id1_1_0_, items1_.id as id1_0_1_, items1_.deleted as deleted2_0_1_, items1_.user as user3_0_1_ from user user0_ left outer join item items1_ on user0_.id=items1_.user and (items1_.deleted=0) where user0_.id=?
select items0_.user as user3_0_0_, items0_.id as id1_0_0_, items0_.id as id1_0_1_, items0_.deleted as deleted2_0_1_, items0_.user as user3_0_1_ from item items0_ where items0_.user=?
```

And as result, I receive user with deleted items in the item list.

Comment: why do you join tables on `deleted` field, which has nothing in common with the foreign key? For HQL you don't need to specify it at all. `from User u left join u.items i where u.id = ?1` must be enough

Comment: I need to join only items with deleted = false field. It's additional join condition.

Comment: if it's a condition, then just move it to `where` part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with creation of two separete queries. One is to get users from user table, other is to get items of related user from items table.

`join` clause is used to combine columns from one or more tables.
`join u.items i on i.deleted = false` is not a proper use. It should be on the `where` clause.

You should change the query this way:

```
@Query("from User u left join u.items i where i.deleted = false and u.id = ?1")
List<User> findUserWithNonDeletedItems(Long userId);
```

Comment: I tried this way, but unfortunately, when I call this method it returns User with deleted employees. I think it is the result of the second query. In this query hibernate select all items, connected with a certain user without ```deleted = false``` condition.

Comment: Can you try `@Query("from User u join fetch u.items i where i.deleted=false and u.id = ?1")`

Comment: It works. But I can't understand, why the ```fetch``` keyword helped me? With ```fetch``` keyword hibernate makes only one SQL query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59468551/6789065 
This answer gave me a full explanation. Thank you!