# Selecting through multiple mapped tables with HQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I'm having a hard time selecting a `Brand` from a given `Country` with HQL.
I've done some reverse engineering so you can picture how my database is modeled:

[To select the `Brand` from the right `Country` I'd have to go through `Address` as well as their `City` and `State`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxAEs.png)

In terms of annotated mappings I've done this:

**Brand**

```
@Table(name = "brand")
public class Brand extends BasicModel {

    private String name;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Address.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name="brand_address",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "address_id") })
    private Set<Address> address;
```

**Address**

```
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address extends BasicModel {

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private AddressCity city;
```

`AddressCity` is mapped to `AddressState` which is mapped to `AddressCountry` in the same fashion that `AddressCity` is mapped by above `Address`.

The table `brand_address` is created automatically by Hibernate.

**Now** with SQL I'd need to join all these tables to get to the `Country` **but** since it's been mapped with Hibernate annotations, how should I write the HQL to select the `Brand` from the given `Country`?

*INFO: When I create a Country containing a set of Address, the table `brand_address` is beign correcly populated.*

**What worked so far** is just selecting the `Brand` and Hibernate will give me back all the populated objects. I can do it with the following:

```
    Query query = session
            .createQuery("from Brand brand " +
                            "where brand.name = :brandName " +
                                "and brand.deleted is null");
    query.setParameter("brandName", brandName);
```

With this, I could easily filter out the `Brands` with that name but from other `Countries`, but it doesn't smell like the best practice...

**What HAVEN'T worked so far** when I tried:

```
    Query query = session
            .createQuery("from Brand brand " +
                            "where brand.name = :brandName " +
                                "and Address.city.state.country.code = :countryCode " +
                                "and brand.deleted is null");
    query.setParameter("brandName", brandName);
    query.setParameter("countryCode", countryCode);
```

AND

```
    Query query = session
            .createQuery("from Brand brand " +
                            "where brand.name = :brandName " +
                                "and AddressCountry.code = :countryCode " +
                                "and brand.deleted is null");
    query.setParameter("brandName", brandName);
    query.setParameter("countryCode", countryCode);
```

How shoudl I work it out?
Is there a way for me to get to the `country` without writing multiple joins in the above queries?
Should I just select it all with the way it has already worked and filter the results back in my DAO?

I've been searching the internet for this but only found information on how to *map and insert* the information, not really about how to write a query that will select through the tables.

I thank in advance any help and suggestions that you beautiful people can send in my way!

**UPDATE 1**: I've tried adding

```
left join brand.address as a
with a.city.state.country.code = :countryCode
```

And it resulted in a new error:

*java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'addresscit3_.state_id' in 'on clause'*

With the following log:

```
14:02:43.646 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor - Using FROM fragment [brand brand0_]
14:02:43.646 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor - Using FROM fragment [inner join address_state addresssta4_ on addresscit3_.state_id=addresssta4_.id]
14:02:43.646 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor - Using FROM fragment [inner join address_country addresscou5_ on addresssta4_.country_id=addresscou5_.id]
14:02:43.647 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor - Using FROM fragment [inner join brand_address addresses1_ on brand0_.id=addresses1_.brand_id inner join address address2_ on addresses1_.address_id=address2_.id and (addresscou5_.code=?)]
14:02:43.647 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor - Using FROM fragment [inner join address_city addresscit3_ on address2_.city_id=addresscit3_.id]
14:02:43.647 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select >> end [level=1, statement=select]
```

**UPDATE 2: SOLUTION**

Using the `with` key as suggested by @guillaume did change the error in such a way that the join order seemed misplaced... A friend of mine suggested using `join fetch` because of the lazy loading and I tweked the query until everything fell in place as follows:

```
    .createQuery("from Brand brand " +
                    "join fetch brand.addresses as a " +
                        "where brand.name = :brandName " +
                        "and a.city.state.country.code = :countryCode " +
                        "and brand.deleted is null");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `Address.city.state.country.code = :countryCode` does not make sense because Address is actually a `Set` of addresses (it would probably be clearer to name it addresses).

Try this instead:

```
from Brand brand
left join brand.address as a
with a.city.state.country.code = :countryCode
```

Comment: I tried this and updated the question with results... I think I'm closer now, thanks!

Comment: The table where you're mapping the `AddressCity` entity does not have a column state_id apparently, I think you need to check your database structure

Comment: I just fixed it and posted to the end of the question, thanks for the idea of adding a join and changing the Set name to addresses! I had to use a fetch instead of the with though, adding the country code to the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "join fetch" your brand entity, your query should work with "join" too.

Check this [What is the difference between JOIN and JOIN FETCH when using JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431312)

Comment: I tried muiltiple different ways, and without the `fetch` it wouldn't work... Maybe there's something somewhere else that I'm missing. Since it's been working so far, I'll leave it as is. Thanks for the link :)